# Unreasonable "cannot borrow `a` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable"?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I have seen [cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35054404/cannot-borrow-as-immutable-because-it-is-also-borrowed-as-mutable) and my question is not a duplicate, since my code has Non-Lexical Lifetimes enabled.

I'm wondering if there is a fundamental reason why the following code:

```
fn f1(a: &u32) {
  print!("{:?}", a);
}

fn main() {
  let mut a = 3;
  let b = &mut a;
  f1(&a);
  *b += 1;
  print!("{:?}", b);
}
```

must result in the following error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `a` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/bin/client/main.rs:91:6
   |
90 |   let b = &mut a;
   |           ------ mutable borrow occurs here
91 |   f1(&a);
   |      ^^ immutable borrow occurs here
92 |   *b += 1;
   |   ------- mutable borrow later used here
```

Now, I know that on the line `f1(&a)`, we'll have one mutable reference (`b`) and one immutable reference (`&a`), and according to [these rules](http://web.mit.edu/rust-lang_v1.25/arch/amd64_ubuntu1404/share/doc/rust/html/book/first-edition/references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules) this can't happen. But having 1 mutable and 1 immutable reference can only cause a problem if their usages are interleaved, right? That is, in theory, shouldn't Rust be able to observe that `b` is not used within `&a`'s existence, and thus accept this program?

Is this just a limitation of the compiler? Or am I overlooking some other memory danger here?

Comment: Out of curiosity, can you not move the `let b = &mut a` declaration below the `f1(&a)` call? Is there something preventing that in your real code?

Comment: In this example, for sure. But in my project, I have some large functions with long scopes. I have some immediately evaluated lambdas in the function too (to leverage the `?` operator). Long story short, non-Lexical Lifetimes has enabled me to write code without ever really fighting the borrow checker, but this situation is the one exception where something overly-restrictive seems to happen.

Comment: @PasinduMuthukuda: "*Long story short, non-Lexical Lifetimes has enabled me to write code without ever really fighting the borrow checker*" I'm not an expert on the language, but isn't that like 80% of the point of Rust: that it syntactically stops you from doing potentially dangerous things? In your case, the safety of the code in `main` depends entirely on what `f1` is doing. And I'm not sure it's a good idea for the validity of syntax to be based on non-local information.

Comment: @NicolBolas "In your case, the safety of the code in main depends entirely on what f1 is doing." I actually can't see how `f1` can break the safety of `main`; can you given an example of what `f1` can do that would mess up `main`?

Comment: @PasinduMuthukuda: It could start a thread and pass it the mutable reference you gave it. A thread that modifies the referenced object, thereby creating a data race.

Comment: I'm... pretty sure you can't simply pass a parameter that's an immutable reference into a thread. That is, `fn f1(a: &u32) { thread::spawn(|| { print!("{:?}", a); }); }` doesn't compile for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> That is, in theory, shouldn't Rust be able to observe that `b` is not used within `&a`'s existence, and thus accept this program?

Maybe, though it's possible that there are edge cases where this would be a problem. I would expect optimisations to be an issue here e.g. eventually Rust will be able to finally tag `&mut` as `noalias` without LLVMs immediately miscompiling things, and in that case your code *would* be UB if it were allowed.

> Is this just a limitation of the compiler?

In this case no, it's literally a limitation of *the language specification*. There are situations which are limitations of the compiler like loop mutations, but here you're trying to do something *the language's rules explicitely and specifically forbid*.

Even [polonius](http://smallcultfollowing.com/babysteps/blog/2018/04/27/an-alias-based-formulation-of-the-borrow-checker/) will not change that.